# How do I get the contents of a nicEdit form when submitting trough ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, nicedit

So what I want to do is to submit a form using jQuery's AJAX function. And the route I choose to go was to use $('#form').serialize(); and then pass that as a GET request. It works out all dandy and fine and dandy until I add the editor, NicEdit, that I'm going to use on the site.

I've researched the issue and the situation is so that once NicEdit takes over a text-area for example, it hides the text-area to the user and instead has her write into a . This data will then be put back into the text-area triggered by the push of a normal submit button.

Now the issue is: I don't have a normal submit button and hence don't trigger the event that puts the data back in the text-area. And I have tried my best to 
<strike>solve the issue</strike> google a solution but everything I've found has been worthless.

Given the fallowing basic setup of my situation: http://jsfiddle.net/MMzhS/1/ - How would you get the data from the NicEdit form to the text-area before alert(); is called?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following as provided by BinaryKitten from #jQuery does the same but a bit cleaner in my opinion: http://jsfiddle.net/MMzhS/5/

Comment: Hi Klaus, i had the same problem however i used .html() instead of .test() because the .text() function sends only the text and not the HTML formatting information which is needed to store the formatting for the text. Am i doing it right??

Comment: This what i was looking for. I needed the html code and not the unformatted text. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 24):

```
var nicE = new nicEditors.findEditor('assignment');
question = nicE.getContent();
```

'assignment' is your textarea id.

the textarea content is save on question variable, hope this will help

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a nicEdit instance

   MyApp.editor = new nicEditor().panelInstance('texarea_id');
2. Let the user enter content to their heart's content! (Pun unintended)
3. Get the content:

   var content = MyApp.editor.instanceById('textarea_id').getContent();
4. Post the content as usual using `content`.

Answer (score 3):

var nicInstance = nicEditors.findEditor('options1');
 var messageContent = nicInstance.getContent();

where options1 is id of textarea

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = $('#peter div').eq(90).text();
```

is the data's information. Also, please use `$.post` instead of `$.get` for form submissions; be nice to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("content").value = "<html><head><title></title><head><body>"+nicEditors.findEditor("this will be your id of your textarea").getContent()+"</body></head></html>";
var templateContent = document.getElementById("content").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

for people who are wondering how to add a custom combobox in nicEdit, here is my blog post to display a custom dropdown with dynamic values

[Link](http://csharpkarma.blogspot.in/2014/10/adding-cutom-dropdow-in-nicedit.html)

Through editing NiceEdit js file we can add custom Combo box in NicEdit

Through Following way we can add dropdown or combobox to NicEdit. You can get dropdown value from database through ajax call and show it in NicEdit
First of all download and implement NicEdit on aspx page
Download the NiceEdit js file and you can enable it by following code (http://nicedit.com/)

```
 <div style="height: 700px; width: 70%; overflow: scroll">                <div id="sample"><script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/nicEdit.js"></script><script src="../nicExample/nicExample.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        bkLib.onDomLoaded(function () {
                            //  nicEditors.allTextAreas()
                            new nicEditor({ fullPanel: true }).panelInstance('area2');});</script>
                    <h4>NicEdit Textarea</h4><textarea name="area2" id="area2" style="width: 70%; height: 700px"> </textarea>
                    </div></div>
```

Now add getddlData() Ajax function in niceEdit.js file in the end of the file

```
// AJAX call
function getddlData() {
    var ajaxResponse;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'NicEdit.aspx/GetBookMarkData', // AJAX call to fecth dropdown data
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        // Text file name
        success: function (response) {
            //    //alert(data.d);    // or do some other data processing
            //   //return data.d;
            ajaxResponse = response;
        }
    });
    return ajaxResponse.d;
}
```

// Add a webMethod in codebehind (.cs file) to fetech dropdown value into nicedit

```
   [WebMethod]
        public static string GetBookMarkData()
        {
///Also you can get DB's data here
            ///  (2 responses dropdown values being filled :  'drop down Value', drop down Text)
            /// Need DB data in , seprated list  Formate:  @@Test@@,TestOne, TestOne,  @@Test2@@,Test2,Test2
            string sbookmarkData = "<<Test_Name>>,Test Name,<<Test_Add>>,Test Add,<<Test_Location>>,Test Location,<<Test_City>>,Test City,<<Test_Phone>>,Test Phone";
            return sbookmarkData;
        }
```

Now open NicEdit js file and copy (Line no 1552) or search following line:

```
var nicEditorFontFormatSelect = nicEditorSelect.extend({

Copy complete function and create another one by changing names etc

var nicEditorInsertBookmark = nicEditorSelect.extend({
    /* By Pankaj Sharma : Not Needed Now  */
    sel: {
        '[[Location]]': "Test Name",
        pre: "Test Address",
        h6: "Test City",
        h5: "Test State",
        h4: "Test Zip",
        h3: "Test ABC",
        h2: "Test One",

    },
    init: function () {
        /* Pankaj Sharma */
        this.setDisplay("Insert Bookmark");
        var response = getddlData();
        var responseArr = response.split(",");
        var strings = [];
        //for (itm in this.sel) {         
        //  //  var A = itm.toUpperCase();
        //    //this.add(  A,  this.sel[itm]  )
        //   }

        for (i = 0; i < responseArr.length; i++) {
            strings.push([responseArr[i], responseArr[i + 1]]);
            i = i + 1;
        }
        for (var i in strings) {
            this.add(strings[i][0], strings[i][1]);
        }
        /* END HERE*/
    },
});
```

Got to line no 1230 or search following line:

var nicSelectOptions = {
    buttons: {
Add following below fontFormat function

'CustomBookmark': {
        name: __('Insert Bookmark'),
        type: 'nicEditorInsertBookmark',  //
        command: 'InsertBookmark'   //InsertBookmark
    }

now updated function should look like this

```
var nicSelectOptions = {
    buttons: {
        'fontSize': {
            name: __('Select Font Size'),
            type: 'nicEditorFontSizeSelect',
            command: 'fontsize'
        },
        'fontFamily': {
            name: __('Select Font Family'),
            type: 'nicEditorFontFamilySelect',
            command: 'fontname'
        },
        'fontFormat': {
            name: __('Select Font Format'),
            type: 'nicEditorFontFormatSelect',
            command: 'formatBlock'
        },
        'CustomBookmark': {
            name: __('Insert Bookmark'),
            type: 'nicEditorInsertBookmark',  //
            command: 'InsertBookmark'   //InsertBookmark
        }
    }
};
```

Now goto line 1385 or
    update: function (A) {
Change it to

```
 update: function (A) {
        //  alert(this.options.command);
        if (this.options.command == 'InsertBookmark') {+
 var editor = nicEditors.findEditor("area2");
        var range = editor.getRng();
        var editorField = editor.selElm();

            editorField.nodeValue = editorField.nodeValue.substring(0, range.startOffset) + A + editorField.nodeValue.substring(range.endOffset, editorField.nodeValue.length);
}
        else {
            // alert(A);  
            /* END HERE */
            this.ne.nicCommand(this.options.command, A);
        }
        this.close()
    }
```

On DropDown options click This will add Drop down value in text Editor on cursor position.

END, you should able to see results

Comment: Adding specific, relevant content from the link you included would help make this answer much more useful for future visitors. [See this related post for more info](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/why-is-linking-bad).

Comment: yes I understand but its a large post, unable to summarise it. Also there is not a single link on google to do that, So writing this post to help others

Comment: Please realize that if that link were to ever go away, this answer would be completely useless for future visitors. Surely, some relevant pieces can be added here to mitigate that scenario. It may take some extra effort, but there are plenty of "large" answers here on StackOverflow.