# nicedit how to remove data from textarea when submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#update').val();
```

is not working how do it?thk

i want remove data in textarea WHEN submit

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../nicEdit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
</script>
<form id="submit">
<textarea name="area1" id="update" cols="40"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="saveResult" value="Save All Data" />
<div id="displayResult"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#saveResult").click(function() {
        //nicEditors.findEditor('update').saveContent();
        var nicE = new nicEditors.findEditor('update');
        firstname = nicE.getContent();
        lastname = $("#lname").val();
        $.post("re.asp",{ update2: firstname, LName2: lastname },function(data) {
            $('#displayResult').append(data);
        });
        $('#update').val();
        $('#lname').val('');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you really should work on formatting the codes..anyways to set an empty value .it should be `$('#update').val('');`

Comment: But @Salman_A please do not indent the CODE 4 spaces from the script tag. It makes the indentation so deep we always have to scroll.

Comment: yes really you can try with nicedit.com richtext editor

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
nicEditors.findEditor( "update" ).setContent( 'value for textarea' );//set value
```

or

```
nicEditors.findEditor( "update" ).setContent( '' );//set empty
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
var nicE = new nicEditors.findEditor('update');
nicE.setContent('');
```

let me know for further help

Comment: For refrence http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207503/how-do-i-get-the-contents-of-a-nicedit-form-when-submitting-trough-ajax

Answer (score 0):

The val() method on input gives the value .It wont set the value.

You have to use

`$('#update').val('');`  //sets empty val in text area

or

`$('#update').val('someDataString');`  //sets the string what ever you have

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, that you could reset a form easily via:

```
document.forms[0].reset()
```

So when you do not only want to reset one specific area, but have to clear a complete form, it would be woth considering.

Answer (score 0):

use this, simple and easy

```
$("div.nicEdit-main").html('');
```

For updating Nicedit you can write

```
$("div.nicEdit-main").html('<h1>Test</h1>');
```