# nicEditor get textarea value in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script>
            <script> 
            //<![CDATA[
            bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
            new nicEditor().panelInstance('area1');
            });
                 $( ".submitCompose" ).click(function() {
                var areaText=$('textarea#area1').val();alert(areaText);
            });
            </script>
```

can i get textarea editor box values using jquery

"area1" is textarea id

Answer (score 1):

```
var nicE = new nicEditors.findEditor('area1');
question = nicE.getContent();
```

`area1` is your textarea id

answer taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8517650